# How can I show that a frame has been duplicated to extend the video framerate using ffprobe?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

As the title suggests, I have a `video.mp4` which I know visually has been extended from 5 fps to 20 fps. I know this because there are 256 frames and when I run ffprobe it reports 20 fps and the video is 12.8 sec long. I also run

```
ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v -show_entries stream=duration_ts,time_base,nb_frames video.mp4
```

reports to me 256 frames, 1/20 timebase and 256 duration. This matches the expected 12.8 s duration. When I manually sort through the extracted frames, I can see the frames have been held for 4 ticks. So it should be 5 fps.

I then run the below to view the packets and the frames (cmd not typed)

```
ffprobe -show_packets -select_streams v:0 video.mp4
```

and the packets or frames don't seem to give me a huge indication that the frames have been duplicated.

With the `-show_packets` cmd the only possible indication of duplication I can see is that every 0.2 seconds, (consistent with 5 fps) the size of the packets go from a consistent 150-300 size to around 16000 or so.

Is there a way I can better articulate what I am seeing with the packet size change? Why has their compression or encoder (forgive any error in verbiage) decided to duplicate frames to achieve 20fps vs. extending the pts to 0.2 seconds for each packet? It seems like simply defining a longer pts would reduce overall file size anyways?

All that said, is there something within ffprobe or other tool I can use to more efficiently confirm what I am visually seeing to say yep these frames were just duplicated from another program? Thanks.